# Preserving <p> tags inside a <blockquote> tag in a Redactor rich text field

Tags: redactor, richtext

If I have multiple paragraphs of text in a rich text field, and I select them all and select "Quote" from the formatting menu, the `<p>` tags are stripped out and replaced with double `<br>` tags, like so:

```
<blockquote>
This is some text.<br><br>
Here's some more text.<br>
</blockquote>
```

Is there any way to preserve the `<p>` tags, like so?

```
<blockquote>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <p>Here's some more text.</p>
</blockquote>
```

I've been through the Redactor documentation and config settings and haven't found anything that seems relevant.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible with Redactor. I tried to add custom formatting styles with the `formattingAdd` config, but it looks like you can't nest block elements, just replace one with another, like you're seeing with `p` and `blockquote`. Wrapping multiple block elements with an inline element is also not possible.

Comment: That's unfortunate. AFAIK, it's perfectly valid to place `<p>` tags and other block elements inside `<blockquote>` tags.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: It's also not possible to add inline styles to headings, so no `em` or `span` in `h2`! And Imperavi has no plans changing this :(

Answer (score 4):

Would you consider an alternative **Matrix** based approach where one rich text field was used for **article-copy** and another separate rich text field, used for the **blockquote**?

So: Matrix field: "Article blocks"

- Block 1: "Article"
- Block 2: "Quote"

e.g. (screen shot from a current project...)

[image: matrix block buttons]

That way you could leverage Matrix functionality and allow more layout control as well - such as alignment etc - to the blockqoutes, and maintain your paragraphs as well.